# s3 socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer python

Tags: python, linux, django, postgresql, amazon-s3

I have a script that takes the postgres backup at some time intervals and uploads the backup to s3. The script was designed more than two years ago and was working perfectly which was deployed on Linux server(`Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)`). But from some days the backup was not being uploaded to s3 and facing some errors and so had a look at the log and it was as below

```
uploading test_db.backup.tar.gz to Amazon S3...............

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/user/projects/test_folder/test/manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/user/projects_envs/testlocal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/user/projects_envs/testlocal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/user/projects_envs/testlocal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/user/projects_envs/testlocal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/user/projects_envs/testlocal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/user/projects/test_folder/test/core/management/commands/db_backup.py", line 41, in handle_noargs
    self.upload_to_s3(file_name, file_path)
  File "/user/projects/test_folder/test/core/management/commands/db_backup.py", line 64, in upload_to_s3
    response = conn.put(settings.BACKUP_BUCKET_NAME, file_name, S3.S3Object(tardata))
  File "/user/projects/test_folder/test/storage/S3.py", line 192, in put
    object.metadata))
  File "/user/projects/test_folder/test/storage/S3.py", line 276, in _make_request
    connection.request(method, path, data, final_headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 805, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 329, in sendall
    v = self.send(data[count:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 298, in send
    v = self._sslobj.write(data)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

**Code**

```
from storage import S3

def upload_to_s3(self, file_name, file_path):
        print "uploading " + file_name +'.tar.gz' + " to Amazon S3..............."

        conn = S3.AWSAuthConnection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
        #get all buckets from amazon S3
        response =  conn.list_all_my_buckets()
        buckets = response.entries
        #is the bucket which you have specified is already there
        flag = False
        for bucket in buckets:
            if bucket.name == settings.BACKUP_BUCKET_NAME:
                flag = True

        #if there is no bucket with that name     
        if flag == False:
            print "There is no bucket with name " + BUCKET_NAME + " in your Amazon S3 account"
            print "Error : Please enter an appropriate bucket name and re-run the script"
            return

        #upload file to Amazon S3
        tardata = open(file_path+'.tar.gz', "rb").read()
        response = conn.put(settings.BACKUP_BUCKET_NAME, file_name, S3.S3Object(tardata))

        ...............
        ...............
```

So whats wrong with the s3 package ? and why it suddenly stopped working ? does this really relates to s3 or else something about linux packages ?

Comment: The error indicates that S3 closed the connection halfway through.  If it only happened once, it's probably just a fluke, but if it's happening all the time, it probably indicates Amazon changed their API.

Comment: @Kevin it was happening all the time