# nginx bad gateway 502 in django

Tags: python, django, sockets, nginx, amazon-s3

I have configured a django developed site using Nginx, gunicorn and supervisor on ubuntu 14.04 and it working perfectly for more than 2 years without any lag in response and request.

1. In my site i have a script/management command that takes the database dump and pushes to s3 through cron job, few days before the code stopped working as started throwing me an error `socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` and i posted the complete traceback [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923059/s3-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer-python) but could n;t get any response and so started googling around, and i got to see this [post](http://scie.nti.st/2008/3/14/amazon-s3-and-connection-reset-by-peer/) and so made changes as describe there like in order to get rid of  `socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` error it was mentioned to add the following lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

   Workaround for TCP Window Scaling bugs in other ppl's equipment

   net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 512000

   net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 512000

I have added them and tried running `$ sudo sysctl -p`, after this executed the dbbackup/s3 uploading command `python manage.py db_backup` but still facing the same `socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` error, and so reverted/removed the changes(removed the above added lines in `/etc/sysctl.conf`) and re run the command `$ sudo sysctl -p` and so i have my previous changes back.

2. Also on my nginx configuration

   ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # SSLv2

I read some where that removing `TLSv1` from above setting ssl_protocols will solve `socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` problem, and so i removed it and restarted nginx server, now tried to run db_backup management command it seems to be working, but i added back `TLSv1` to setting ssl_protocols just to make sure and confirm with some one else

Now the actual problem is after doing the above changes and reverting back and restarting supervisor, nginx my site has became damn damn slow

I have different sections on site like

1. Home page
2. Contact us
3. Many pages that shows/list the list of records fetching from postgres database

The home page and contact us page are working as usual but the page that related to database fetching was not able to load even after 3 minutes and displaying `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)`

I tried everything like restarting postgres, nginx, supervisor and double checked the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make sure it does n't any new changes. Everything seems to be perfect but could n;t able to understand why the site has gone slow

**Nginx and gunicorn files**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  example.com  www.example.com  m.example.com;

  location / {
    return 301    https://www.example.com$request_uri;
#    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
  }

  location /static/ {
    alias /user/apps/example_webapp/project/new_media/;
  }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  example.com  www.example.com  m.example.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/example/example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/example/www.example.com.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  20m;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;  # ~ 40,000 sessions
    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # SSLv2
#    ssl_ciphers          ALL:!aNull:!eNull:!SSLv2:!kEDH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP:@STRENGTH;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    }

  location /static/ {
    alias /user/apps/example_webapp/project/new_media/;
  }

}
```

**Gunicorn**

```
bind = "127.0.0.1:8001"
workers = 3
loglevel = "debug"
proc_name = "project"
daemon = False
pythonpath = "/user/apps/project_name/"
errorlog = "/user/apps/gunicorn_configurations/gunicorn_logfiles/gunicorn_errors.log"
timeout = 90
```

So can anyone please let me know how to bring my site back to original state ? also what might be the causes for slowed up suddenly without any reason ? where should i check for any help or errors ?

Comment: Does the speed issue happen when TLSv1 **is** removed?  In which case could you just do away with this as it would only effect older browsers?